# Can sum of rationals be irrational?

Tags: summation

I have seen proof of -: Sum of two rationals is rational and that implies that sum of all rational is always rational( by induction). Now my question is about Basel Problem-:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem. How can the sum of rationals be equal to an irrational number?

Comment: Induction doesn't apply to infinite sums. You know by induction that any finite sum of rationals is a rational.

Comment: Sum of **finitely** many rationals is rational.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116269/how-can-adding-an-infinite-number-of-rationals-yield-an-irrational-number.

Comment: Note that every irrational number is an infinite sum of rational numbers (let $x$ be irrational and let's assume that $0 < x < 1$ let $x_k$ be the $k-th$ decimal place of $x$. Then $x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k\cdot 10^{-k}$ and each $x_k \cdot 10^{-k}$ is rational.

Comment: An easy example of rationals adding up to an irrational:$$\pi=3+0.1+0.04+0.001+0.0005+\dotsb$$

Comment: The key thing to note is that an infinite sum is not just "a sum." It is a limit of a bunch of sums. Lots of things you expect from finite sums don't work in infinite sums - re-arrange an infinite sum, for example, and you get different results.

Comment: A series is not a sum.

Answer (score 5):

You're interpreting the sum wrong. Actually, the sum means

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{k^2}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^N \frac 1{k^2}$$

And the limit of a sequence of rational numbers can definitely be irrational.

Answer (score 4):

The sum of two rationals is rational, therefore, by induction the sum of *a finite number* of rationals is rational, but induction can't prove anything about sums of infinitely many rational numbers.

Induction tells you that if something is true for $1$, and if it being true for $n$ implies it's true for $n+1$, then it's true *for all finite $n$*. It doesn't allow you to say anything about infinity. For instance, you can prove by induction that the sum of $n$ numbers is finite. That doesn't mean that the sum of infinitely many numbers is always finite.