# About the sum of series like $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n^{-2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n^{-2}=\pi^2/6$, but shouldn't the sum of rationals be rational? Is this akin to $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n=-1/12$? Or does that mean that, somehow, $\pi^2/6$ is rational?

Comment: Not necessarily an *infinite* sum....

Comment: The sum of rationals, indeed, is rational. The limit of a sum of infinite rationals isn't necessarily, though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$3$ is rational. So is $3 + 0.1$. So is $3 + 0.1 + 0.04$. So is $3 + 0.1 + 0.04 + 0.001$. So is $3 + 0.1 + 0.04 + 0.001 + 0.0005$. But the limit of this series, $\pi$, is irrational.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. I'll delete mine.

Comment: You were both beaten by https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116270/42969 :)

Answer (score 1):

The sum of rationals is rational, but $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^2}$ is not a sum of rational numbers. It's a *series*, and therefore the *limit* of a specific kind of sequencs: in this case, of the sequence $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^nk^{-2}$. Of course limits of sequences of rational numbers need not be rational.

Comment: I cannot find the word summatory in any dictionary.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SummatoryFunction.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer using the topology wording. *Topology* is the branch of mathematics that deals with continuity, limits, etc...

The value of a convergent  series is the limit of its partial sums. As the set of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ isn't closed, this limit can be in $\mathbb{R \backslash Q}$.

Besides, the second sum you mention $\sum n=-1/12$, is regularly seen on Math SE ; it is the equivalent of a mathematical (baseless) rumor...

**Bibliography** : If you want to know more about topology, see the downloadable book [Topology without tears](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/200026970_Topology_without_tears#fullTextFileContent).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and recommendation monsieur! And about the sum, yes, that is why I used "akin" in my wording; it intuitively seems absurd anyhow.

Comment: * not to say that mathematics is always in the range of the intuitive, but this one is a bit "too much".

Comment: I agree. Our mind isn't well "programmed" to deal with infinity :)

Comment: About counterintuitive results in mathematics, see for [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2040811)

Comment: See also [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/139699) or, [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/48301) in another "range"